# Url escaped parameter not resolving properly

Tags: go, swagger, mux

I have generated a simple `gorilla/mux` API using swagger.
For my single endpoint `/v1/abc/{arg}` I am passing an argument.

Therefore a request like: `http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/hello` simply echos the argument for now.
The following function handles the request:

```
func GetAbcByArg(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    arg, _ := url.QueryUnescape(vars["arg"])
    log.Printf("arg %s", arg)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", arg)
}
```

So far so good. However, whenever I try to pass some special characters as the argument, I get a 404 error and the handler is not called. I though I could simply escape the argument by fully escaping URL characters (rfc3986), but that is also not working. Why? How can I prepare any string so I can pass it in a single element?

Examples:

`http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/hello` working as expected

`http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/123/xyz` not working as expected

`http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/a.x` working as expected

`http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/https://google.com` not working as expected

`http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com` not working, **but why**?

## UPDATE

Route setup:

```
var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "GetAbcByArg",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/v1/abc/{arg}",
        GetAbcByArg,
    },
}
```

Comment: Please post the code where you set up the routes.  Based on your example "working/not working", it seems that you want a `PathPrefix` route...   (Solidi have a special meaning in URLs; they separate path elements.  Your route will match exactly one path element as {arg}.)

Comment: I have added the route. However, why is the argument separated even though I am escaping it?

Answer (score 3):

It is working with

`router := mux.NewRouter().SkipClean(true).UseEncodedPath()`

ref: https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/mux.go

Answer (score 0):

Replacing one of the / in this pages address is still pointing to this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716545%2Furl-escaped-parameter-not-resolving-properly

So I guess

http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

Is seen as 
http://localhost:9090/v1/abc/https%3A//google.com

By your router and it doesn't seem to allow any more than one part after abc

Comment: See https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/77 and https://github.com/lighthouse-isu/lighthouse/issues/30